# polynomial with a root but no linear factor

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

I have proven that if $R$ is UFD, $f(x) \in R[x]$, then $f(x)$ has a root $r\in R$ if and only if $f$ has a linear factor over $R$.

Is this true for rings in general, or domains in general? I have been trying to construct an example of a polynomial in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$ with a root but no linear factor, but I cannot seem to find an example.

Comment: $2x-3\in\Bbb{Z}[x]$ obviously has a linear factor over $\Bbb{Z}$, but does it have a root in $\Bbb{Z}$?

Comment: good point, i guess my proof only works if R is a field. I am really looking for an example of a polynomial with a root but no linear factor.

Comment: Don't we always have $f(x)=g(x)(x-r)+f(r)$ for some polynomial $g(x)\in R[x]$ that we can construct by long division? Implying that if $r$ is a zero, then $x-r$ is a right factor. This much works even for non-commutative $R$ (but there will be complications if you try to extract more than one factor in the non-commutative case). Granted that the polynomial ring over a non-commutative ring is not the most natural object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The implication $f$ has a root $\implies$ $f$ has a linear factor is true over any unitary ring.

**Proof** Since $1$ is an unit in $R$, we can do long division by $x-a$ in $R[X]$. Then 
$$f(x)=(x-a)Q(x)+R(x)$$
with $R$ a constant polynomial. Plugging in $a$ we get $R=0$, therefore $x-a$ is a factor of $f(x)$.

**P.S.** The problem in non UFD case is what do we mean by a factor. For example in $\mathbb Z/6\mathbb Z[X]$ we have
$$X^2-5X=(X-2)(X-3)=X(X-5)$$

Can we call all these factors of $f$?

Comment: The roots of $x^2-5x$ over $\mathbb{Z}/6$ are $r=0,2,3,5$. In this sense, $x,x-2,x-3,x-5$ are all "factors". But a decomposition is not unique, of course.

Answer (score 3):

The first claim that $f(x)$ has a root if and only if $f$ has a linear factor is not true for UFDs. Just consider the product of linear factors of the form $ax+b$ such that $a\neq 0$ is not a unit in $R$ (of course this does not exist if $R$ is a field). Jyrki already gave an example. 
However, the division algorithm for polynomials works in $R[X]$ for *any* ring $R$, provided that the leading coefficient of the divisor is a unit. So if there is a root $r$, then we can divide by $(x-r)$. Hence there is no polynomial over a ring having a root but no linear factor.