# $f$ has a root in $k \implies$ that $f$ is reducible...only true for $k = $ field?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory

Let $f \in k[x]$, where $k[x]$ is a ring of polynomials with coefficients in $k$. Suppose: $f$ has a root in $k \implies$  that $f$ is reducible. Is this statement only true when $k = $ a field?

Comment: This is not even true for fields. $f=2X$ has a root in $\Bbb Q$, but is irreducible in $\Bbb Q[X]$, since $2$ is a unit.

Comment: When $k$ is a ring you can write $p(x)=p((x-r)+r)=\sum_{k=0}^na_k(x-r)^k$. If $p(r)=0$, then $a_0=0$. Therefore, $p(x)=(x-r)\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_k(x-r)^{k-1}$.

Comment: Not at all. If $A$ is *any* commutative ring and $f(x)$ in $A[x]$ has $f(a) = 0$ for some $a \in A$ then $f(x) = (x-a)g(x)$ for some $g(x) \in A[x]$. Division with remainder by monic polynomials works over all commutative rings.

Comment: So, if I change the assumption that $k[x]$ is a commutative ring, will that fix things?

Comment: Something that contradicts Eisensteins criterion.

Comment: What if we say that $deg(f) \geqslant 2$?

Comment: @Dietrich One needs to be careful about the denotation of (ir)reducible in polynomial rings, e.g. some definitions consider $2X$ irreducible in $\,\Bbb Z[X]$ and some don't. And for rings with zero-divisors there are various definitions of associate and irreducible. So precise definitions are *essential*.

Answer (score 2):

Let $R$ be a (commutative) ring. If $f\in R[X]$ has a root then $f$ has a linear factor:

[polynomial with a root but no linear factor](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2077837/polynomial-with-a-root-but-no-linear-factor)

This does not always imply that $f$ is reducible, consider for example $f=2X\in \Bbb Q[X]$ which has a rational root but is irreducible.

However, for non-constant polynomials, or monic polynomials over an integral domain $R$, having a root implies reducibility.

*Definition*: A polynomial $f\in R[X]$ over an integral domain $R$ is *irreducible* if $f$ is not a unit in $R$ and whenever
$f=gh$ with $g,h\in R[X]$, we have $g$ or $h$ is a unit of $R$.

Comment: The final sentence does not parse. Also see my comment on the question.

Comment: To be precise, you should state the definition of "irreducible" that you are using.

Comment: Why use $2X$ when $X$ is also irreducible and has a root?

Comment: @Kolja Because of the difference between $\Bbb Q[X]$ and $\Bbb Z[X]$. In $\Bbb Z[X]$, $2X$ is reducible since $2$ is not a unit. In $\Bbb Q[X]$ it is irreducible. With $f(X)=X$ we can't see this, but otherwise it would of course also work here.

Comment: @Kolja And its more complex over non-domains, e.g. $\,x = (2x-3)(3x+2)\,$ over $\,\Bbb Z_6 = $ integers $\bmod 6.\,$ Hence my insistence on precision and rigor above.